# How to call a Put method from a Post method in the rest controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, spring-restcontroller

i have 2 methods, the first one is a PUT method and the second one is a POST method and i want to call the first one in the second one but it doesn't work.

Here's my code :

**PUT Method**

```
@PutMapping("/classifs")
public ResponseEntity<Classif> updateClassif(@Valid @RequestBody Classif classif) throws URISyntaxException {
    Classif result = classifRepository.save(classif);

    return ResponseEntity.ok();
}
```

**POST Method**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/classifs/maj", headers = "accept=application/json")
public void tableauClassif(@RequestBody ClassificationHolder classificationHolder) {
    for(ClassifLineHolder line :  classificationHolder.getDetails()){
        for(Classif c : line.getMapClassif().values()){
            if(c.getId() != null && c.getId() !=0)
                this.updateClassif(c); //this i what i tried to do but it does'nt work !!
            else
                classifRepository.save(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but it doesn't work." Can you be more specific, like if you getting compilation error, or any exceptions while calling your post?

Comment: the IDE doesn't accept it... it signale an error

Comment: add `throws URISyntaxException` to your  tableauClassif method signature and it will not show error. or you can add try/catch block.

Comment: the URISyntaxException is in the method that i wan't to call !! i wan't to call updateClassif in the method tableauClassif that's why i did this : this.updateClassif(c);

Comment: problem is your `updateClassif` throws `URISyntaxException` exception, which is not handled in your `tableauClassif` method. You either need to add throw signature to your `tableauClassif` method or you need to handle it by catching exception when exception is thrown by `updateClassif` method.  so `try { this.updateClassif(c);  } catch (URISyntaxException e) { }` will work for you. Otherwise your code will not compile.

Comment: It works ! thank you :-)